# Looking for BIND web interface

Tags: gui, bind, webapps

I currently manage the domains of many clients and would like to setup a BIND server so I can all manage them from one place. Now, I'm looking for a web interface to BIND that would let my clients manage their domains by themselves in case they wanted to. What web apps would be well suited for this? I'm looking for something that will only do DNS management, not something more complete like Webmin.

Comment: I don't know of any good ones. I ended up writing my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ProBIND is a Web application for administrating one or more BIND servers
Download at http://probind.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

There's a newer web app that might do what you are looking for called fmDNS (http://www.facilemanager.com/modules/fmdns/).

Answer (score 3):

I've never used a web interface other than webmin.

But, here's a list I found at Debian Help:
http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/bindweb.htm

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late, but for other searching and stopping by...I've been looking for at Linux/*buntu GUI to manage DNS/BIND for years too.

The only one I've come up with for many years is the YAST2 Bind Manager included in OpenSUSE, but not installed by default in recent years.

This lasted until I recently found OpenPanel at http://www.openpanel.org. It's a great plugin/module build application, consisting of selectable modules for Bind9, Apache, Firewall, Postfix, MySQL, SSH, SSL, Spamassassin. Using an minimal installation of Debian or a *buntu distro, and installing the modules:
 openpanel-minimal, openpanel-mod-dnsdomain, openpanel-mod-iptables
and a few dependencies, you'd get a nice web, or if you wish a openpanel Cisco like CLI, managed DNS server with simple firewall (iptables) managment too.

You could have a look at their nice demo first, and checkout all the modules besides DNS at: https://demo.openpanel.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know its not what you asked, but look at Isp Omega http://isp-control.net/.
It contains tools to help manage the domains, and creates DNS entries (from a template) for domains.